# Remove the built in ad from chrome

Tags: google-chrome

On the new tab page in chrome, I see this:

[image]

I don't know what gave Google the crazy idea that I would like having ads in my browser but I absolutely do not.

Extensions (such as adblock) don't work on chrome pages so I can't use anything to hide it. Is there a setting to get rid of it?

Comment: If only there was some way you could get a real person to help you figure out how to remove the ad in real time.

Comment: Actually, this should be easy to deal with, but unfortunately I am unable to get it to happen, so I can’t make a fix at the moment. If I can figure out a way to get the ad to show (I don’t remember the last time I saw one), then I’ll whip something up. In the meantime, I remember [reading something](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/crv9NngOunA) about disabling the ads (temporarily?) by clicking the `ⓧ` a specific number of times; but then that probably doesn’t work.

Comment: @Synetech I don't see any X anywhere

Comment: @chipperyman573, oh you’re right. I didn’t notice that in your screenshot. I guess they removed the ability to remove the add *at all*. This is just another example of how evil Google has become. I wouldn’t be surprised if it still shows ads in Chromium even though that is supposed to be a non-branded FOSS version.

Answer (score 0):

you should try comodo dragon browser same as google chrome.
[Download From Here](http://www.comodo.com/home/browsers-toolbars/browser.php)

it does not have any google ads.

Comment: I like chrome though.

Comment: `I like chrome though.`   @chipperyman573, why? What does Google Chrome have that other distros don’t? If you do switch to a different distro, in addition to Comodo Dragon, I would recommend either [SRWare Iron](http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron.php) or simply [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/Home).

Comment: @chipperyman573 [link](http://ws-technologies.wonderhowto.com/how-to/chrome-shares-your-activity-with-google-heres-use-comodo-dragon-block-0132365) you should read it.
google chrome share lots of things with google so it might not be that much secure as dragon that's why i prefer dragon over chrome.

Comment: I don't mind not being secure. I'm well aware of all the things that google shares about me and I like it over all the benefits (sync, extensions, themes, etc)